# Defining an action on $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$ such that the orbit space is homeoomorphic to the Möbius band?

Tags: general-topology

By Möbius band I mean the quotient space obtained from $[0,1]^2$ by identifying (0,y) with (1,1-y). Not syre how to show that a given orbit space is homeomorphic tl a given space.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be the group generated by the homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (x+1,1-y)$. Then, $G$ acts on $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$ on the  left and the quotient is homeomorphic to the Moebius band.

Comment: How would you prove that the quotient is homeomorphic to the Möbius band?

Comment: Let $\pi:\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]\rightarrow (\mathbb{R}\times [0,1])/G$ the quotient projection. And let $q:[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow M$ the quotient projection from your definition for the Moebius band (M denoting Moebius band). Then we have the restricted function $\pi:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow (\mathbb{R}\times [0,1])/G$ such that $\pi(x)=\pi(y)$ when $q(x)=q(y)$, so $\pi$ descends to the Moebius band defining a continuous function $\overline{\pi}:M\rightarrow (\mathbb{R}\times [0,1])/G$. Now, if you prove that $\overline{\pi}$ is bijective, since $M$ is compact it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: So, what is G in detail? According to the definition of group action, it is necessary to check that hg(x)=h(g(x)), where h, g are in G; e(x)=x, where e is the identity of G, and that the function GxRx[0,1] is continuous.

Comment: Ivy, the group G is by definition the subgroup inside the group of all homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$, which is generated by the homeomorphism defined above. You can put the discrete topology on G so that it is a topological group. Since it is a group of homeomorphisms the action will be continuous, if you are confused pick the book Introductions to topological manifolds 2nd edition (by John Lee) and look at prop 3.87.